# scala - pass self type annotated class to child object

Tags: scala, inversion-of-control

sorry if that's a dumb title, i don't know how to express this clearly

say i have a logging trait:

```
trait Logging {
    def log(s:String)
}
```

and then some implementation

```
trait PrintlnLog extends Logging {
    def log(s:String) { println(s) }
}
```

which i use like this

```
class SomeProcess { this:Logging =>
   def doSomeJunk() {
      log("starting junk")
      ...
      log("junk finished")
   }
}
```

i could use this class like

```
val p = new SomeProcess () with PrintLog
p.doSomeJunk()
```

now what if i have this

```
class SubProcess { this:Logging => 
   def doSubJunk() {
      log("starting sub junk")
      ...
      log("finished sub junk")
   }
}

class ComplexProcess { this:Logging => 
   def doMoreJunk() {
       log("starting more junk")
       val s = new SubProcess with // ??? <-- help!
       s.doSubJunk()
       log("finished more junk")
   }
}
```

in ComplexProcess i want to instantiate a SubProcess mixing in the same logging trait that has been mixed into ComplexProcess, but ComplexProcess doesn't know what that is. is there a way to get a reference to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. In this case, you'd probably do something like this:

```
trait WithSubProcess {
  def s: SubProcess
}

class ComplexProcess { this: Logging with WithSubProcess ... }
```

Comment: this is essentially what i'm doing, but it's ugly because i have all these traits scattered throughout my code whose sole purpose is to cake-in logging. was hoping there was a better way

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, by definition, no. Scala is a statically-typed language, so this information is only really available at compile time. With a more extensive reflection API and some composition/assembly hacks it might be possible in the future, though that's steering dangerously close to Aspect Oriented Programming, as Paolo mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Logging is a typical case for Aspect Oriented Programming. You may try using AspectJ with scala: see [this article by Jonas Boner](http://java.dzone.com/articles/real-world-scala-managing-cros)